# Finding maximum of quadratic function that depends on other variables

Tags: r, regression, polynomial, extreme-value

I am trying to fit a model of the following form in R:

```r
yield = solar_rad + I(solar_rad ^ 2)
```

where each observation is a field and `solar_rad` is the sum of solar radiation while a field was in the ground. I have about 10,000 observations.

I find a negative quadratic relationship between yield and total solar radiation 
as expected. My question is how I should think about interacting other variables such as temperature with solar rad because I suspect the optimal solar rad will depend on temperature (higher temperature requires less solar rad).

For example, should I do this:

`yield = I(solar_rad ^ 2) + temp_avg * solar_rad`

Or:

`yield = (solar_rad + I(solar_rad ^ 2)) * solar_rad`

It gets even more complicated when I consider other variables such as variety. So I might have something like this:

`yield = (solar_rad + I(solar_rad ^ 2)) * temp_avg * variety1`

How am I supposed to determine which interactions to include?

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is small I would suggest generating all interaction terms you can think of first. This could be done with domain expertise (knowledge of possible interaction for example in the form of physics formula) or automatically generate everything for example with automatic feature engineering or for your case I you could probably use sklearn PolynomialFeatures up to degree 2. Please do not forget to apply standardization after that.

The next step you can do feature selection. For your case you could use Lasso regression. If you haven't used lasso before it is simply a linear regression with $L_1$ norm weight regularization. This have unique properties of pushing less useful feature weights to 0 and hence you could consider removing those features.

Comment: I am very interested in interacting with sklearn PolynomialFeatures from within R, particularly in passing data and coefficients between them. can you please point to an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318558/polynomial-feature-expansion-in-r https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/42738/generating-polynomial-features-in-r this is what you are probably looking for. I myself am not really advanced R user so this is as far as I could help. Hopefully it is enough.